# Equivalent sequence/stepper relay to "FINDER - 20.21.9.012.4000"

Tags: relay, dc, ac, ac-dc

I am currently looking at this relay: [FINDER - 20.21.9.012.4000](http://uk.farnell.com/finder/20-21-9-012-4000/relay-step-modular-16a-12vdc/dp/1765065?Ntt=1765065). Which is step relay, that makes contact AC output active with coil input DC (12V) [which i need]; and disconnects output when coil is triggered again. Which works like this GIF animation: http://www.homofaciens.de/bilder/technik/relay_002a.gif.

**Q1:** It says that Un=12VDC (coil input), coil resistance R=27Ω and current over the coil must be 400mA. Have I read this data correct? --*Coil specifications, PDF, page 2*-- So if I needed to switch 16x same relays at the same time, input current consumption would be 7A?

**Q2:** Where in the specification is the info, that tells me how much time must the coil be on high state, to activate/trigger the contact output?

This relay is kinda expensive for me, since I need around 30 pieces...

**Q3:** Does it exists equivalent relay, that is described, which:

- contact doesn't need to have 16A output, it can easily have max 1A, since burden will only be simple lights, that will probably have max 0,5A consumption;
- I need DIN-rail package, but it can be for PCB, and I will find PCB to DIN-rail socket ([example](http://si.farnell.com/te-connectivity/pt78720/socket-for-pt2-din-screw-terminal/dp/9913807));
- and has some kind of reasonable coil current.

Thanks

Comment: **Q2:** The [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/467587.pdf) lists the "minimum impulse duration" as 0.1 seconds (100 ms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Yes, it does say Un = 12V DC, Coil resistance R = 27Ω, and Consumption I at UN = 440mA

So, yes if you wanted to drive 16 relays *at the same time* it wouyld need 16 * 440mA = 7.04A

Q2: "Minimum/Maximum impulse duration: 0.1s/1h (according to EN 60669)"
i.e. it must be triggered for at least 0.1 seconds, minimum

Q3: Are you asking a question about an alternative part, or a "shopping question"?
That is off-topic. See the [Help Centre](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) to understand why.

Comment: Thanks for the Q1 and Q2 confirmation. About the Q3: I thought it is allowed, because I searched the site before asking the questions, where I found a lot of questions with ["help me find equivalent"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=equivalent+is%3Aquestion) phrases. Can you at least point me to the right website/forum, where I can find or ask for replacement?

Comment: @Glavić - the most obvious place to ask for an equivalent is Farnell's element14. You might try any distributer directly too.

Comment: Was on the chat with Farnell support, they could not find me the replacement. It obviously doesn't exists :(